# how to use model function in javascript?

Tags: javascript, ajax

on success function i am receiving an array and passing it to blade view every thing works fine but problem is that here is a model function(product) which i can use in bade like this `<td>{{ $preport->product->name }}</td>` but i want to use it in javascript so i tried this code

```
   success: function (data) {
                    var getsellerreport = data.getsellerreport;
                    
                     var output = `<tbody>
                    ${getsellerreport.map(function(preport) {
                      return `<tr><td>${preport.product_id}</td>`+
                             '<td>${preport->product->name}</td><tr>`;
                    }).join('\n')}
                  </tbody>`;
}
```

**as you can see i used this `'<td>${preport->product->name}</td>` but gived me error in consle ">" is it possible to access model function in javascript if it is then how i can access it?**

Comment: There is a single quote ' on the left side of the string and a backtick ` on the right side of the string. That's one of the problems.

Comment: JS uses dots instead of arrows, you're already using those in the previous line. And if you want to insert variables into strings, the string has to be delimited by backticks, again as you already do in the previous line. The preport.product_id line is fine; just use the same syntax in the next line.

Comment: i tried ${preport.product.name} now error is name is not defined

Answer (score 1):

you should merge your product name with getsellerreport from controller and then simply use it as you above used.